# Polynomial greatest common divisor

Tags: polynomials

[image]

I can solve part a) and c) but have no idea for part b).

Can anybody help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOY6Y.jpg)[image]

I think there is a problem with part (b) as we can see from part(c) that given relations doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) for polynomials..

Comment: Then why does it flops on this example ?